# Symfony 4 / doctrine child entity returning only first row

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to learn symfony and i have a problem with fetching data in object. The child entity get only the first row of query result. How can i get the correct data ?

Here my team entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use App\Entity\Races;

/**
 * Teams
 *
* @ORM\Table(name="teams", 
indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_owned_by_coach_id", 
columns={"owned_by_coach_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_teams_races_idx", columns={"f_race_id"})})

 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Teams
 {
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="team_id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $teamId;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=60, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="treasury", type="bigint", nullable=true)
 */
private $treasury;

/**
 * @var bool|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="apothecary", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $apothecary;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="rerolls", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $rerolls;

/**
 * @var bool|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ff_bought", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $ffBought;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ass_coaches", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $assCoaches;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cheerleaders", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $cheerleaders;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="rdy", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default"="1"})
 */
private $rdy = '1';

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="retired", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $retired = '0';

/**
 * @var bool|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ff", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $ff;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tv", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $tv;

/**
 * @var float|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="elo", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
 */
private $elo;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="year", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $year;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="stadium", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"default"="99"})
 */
private $stadium = '99';

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="stadium_name", type="string", length=60, nullable=false, options={"default"="green meadow"})
 */
private $stadiumName = 'green meadow';

/**
 * @var \Coaches
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Coaches")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owned_by_coach_id", referencedColumnName="coach_id")
 * })
 */
private $ownedByCoach;

/**
 * @var \Races
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Races", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="f_race_id", referencedColumnName="race_id")
 */
private $fRace;

public function getTeamId(): ?int
{
    return $this->teamId;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(?string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

public function getTreasury(): ?int
{
    return $this->treasury;
}

public function setTreasury(?int $treasury): self
{
    $this->treasury = $treasury;

    return $this;
}

public function getApothecary(): ?bool
{
    return $this->apothecary;
}

public function setApothecary(?bool $apothecary): self
{
    $this->apothecary = $apothecary;

    return $this;
}

public function getRerolls(): ?int
{
    return $this->rerolls;
}

public function setRerolls(?int $rerolls): self
{
    $this->rerolls = $rerolls;

    return $this;
}

public function getFfBought(): ?bool
{
    return $this->ffBought;
}

public function setFfBought(?bool $ffBought): self
{
    $this->ffBought = $ffBought;

    return $this;
}

public function getAssCoaches(): ?int
{
    return $this->assCoaches;
}

public function setAssCoaches(?int $assCoaches): self
{
    $this->assCoaches = $assCoaches;

    return $this;
}

public function getCheerleaders(): ?int
{
    return $this->cheerleaders;
}

public function setCheerleaders(?int $cheerleaders): self
{
    $this->cheerleaders = $cheerleaders;

    return $this;
}

public function getRdy(): ?bool
{
    return $this->rdy;
}

public function setRdy(bool $rdy): self
{
    $this->rdy = $rdy;

    return $this;
}

public function getRetired(): ?bool
{
    return $this->retired;
}

public function setRetired(bool $retired): self
{
    $this->retired = $retired;

    return $this;
}

public function getFf(): ?bool
{
    return $this->ff;
}

public function setFf(?bool $ff): self
{
    $this->ff = $ff;

    return $this;
}

public function getTv(): ?int
{
    return $this->tv;
}

public function setTv(?int $tv): self
{
    $this->tv = $tv;

    return $this;
}

public function getElo(): ?float
{
    return $this->elo;
}

public function setElo(?float $elo): self
{
    $this->elo = $elo;

    return $this;
}

public function getYear(): ?bool
{
    return $this->year;
}

public function setYear(bool $year): self
{
    $this->year = $year;

    return $this;
}

public function getStadium(): ?int
{
    return $this->stadium;
}

public function setStadium(int $stadium): self
{
    $this->stadium = $stadium;

    return $this;
}

public function getStadiumName(): ?string
{
    return $this->stadiumName;
}

public function setStadiumName(string $stadiumName): self
{
    $this->stadiumName = $stadiumName;

    return $this;
}

public function getOwnedByCoach(): ?Coaches
{
    return $this->ownedByCoach;
}

public function setOwnedByCoach(?Coaches $ownedByCoach): self
{
    $this->ownedByCoach = $ownedByCoach;

    return $this;
}

public function getFRace(): ?Races
{
    return $this->fRace;
}

public function setFRace(?Races $fRace): self
{
    $this->fRace = $fRace;

    return $this;
}


}
```

Here my race entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Races
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="races")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Races
 {
/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="race_id", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $raceId;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=60, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cost_rr", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $costRr;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="icon", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $icon;

public function getRaceId(): ?bool
{
    return $this->raceId;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(?string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

public function getCostRr(): ?int
{
    return $this->costRr;
}

public function setCostRr(?int $costRr): self
{
    $this->costRr = $costRr;

    return $this;
}

public function getIcon(): ?string
{
    return $this->icon;
}

public function setIcon(?string $icon): self
{
    $this->icon = $icon;

    return $this;
}


}
```

how i fetch the data in my controller

```
$teams = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository(Teams::class)
              ->findAll();
```

This is what I get:

[image]

The child entity show always the first row....

Comment: It's a typo, i'm correcting my post.

Comment: You have defined one to one relationship so what is the exact issue/expected output ?

Comment: Each team must have a races ex : team 1 -> elves, team 2 -> dwarf etc, team 3  -> Ork etc... Now it's team 1 -> elves, team 2 elves etc... And the data are correct in db

Comment: Remove * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE") above $fRace property. and change the annotations of your Race->race_id property to     /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="race_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */ Read https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional

Comment: yeah !! It work ! i must learn to not trust auto generated files !! thanks for your help everybody!!!